# How can I get dataGridView user input?

Tags: c#, datagridview, user-input

How to detect and get user input from dataGridView cell?

For example, I want to put an integer into a cell and after I submit, it would make the calculations using it.

Solution:

I chose CellValidated event

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidated(object send, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   label1.Text = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
}
```

Simply, it will give you the value of the last edited cell and show it in the label.

Thanks for giving references.

Comment: Look at the `CellEndEdit, CellValidating, CellValidated` and `CellValueChanged` events.

Answer (score 0):

Implement CellEndEdit event and use the cell property FormattedValue/EditedFormattedValue to get the edited value.